# Multiple ifelse function inside a mutate in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a `new column`, that looks into whether the `column 1` in dataframe A matches to  `column 1` in dataframe B, and if is there a match to have the value in column `output` in dataframe B. If `column 1` in dataframe A does not a find a match in `column 1` in dataframe B. To look at whether there is match between `column 2` in dataframe A and `column 2` dataframe B, and if there is a match to have the `output 2` from dataframe B. If there is no matches then for it to be zero.

This is my attempt, I think it semi works but it gives me a lot of NAs, a lot of these NAs are false because there is match in columns between the dataframes but it still comes up as NA. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 dataframeA<-dataframeA %>% mutate(newcolumn=ifelse(column1 %in% dataframeB$column1, dataframeB$output, ifelse(column2 %in% dataframeB$column2, dataframeB$output2,NA)))
```

I tried to use `case_when` but this doesn't work because I want the output value to be from a column.

EDIT here is some sample data from the help of @bloxx

```
dataframeA<- data.frame(Column1 = c("a", "b", "c", "f"),
                    Column2 = c("a", "a", "a", "f"))
dataframeB<- data.frame(Column1 = c("b", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
                    Column2 = c("a", "b", "a", "e"),
                    Output = c("B", "B", "B", "B","B","B","B"),
                    Output2 = c("D", "D", "D", "D"))
dataframeA <- dataframeA %>% 
mutate(new_variable = ifelse(Column1 %in% dataframeB$Column1, 
dataframeB$Output,
ifelse(Column2 %in% 
dataframeB$Column2,dataframeB$Output2, 0 )))
```

In my dataset, dataframeB has different lengths, but even if make it the same length, there is a lot of NAs.

Thank you

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a small example of your data used.

Comment: This question will (most likely) improve and get better answers if you provide sample data and a desired output.

Comment: Your question sounds more like a join than an ifelse-problem to me. Take a look at dplyr's `left_join` and `coalesce` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I used a `for` loop to do so. But there's probably a more efficient and elegant solution using `purrr`. Anyway:

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  value2 = c(2,5,8,4,6))

df2 <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,2,3,8,5),
                  value2 = c(2,9,8,4,7),
                  output1 = c(4,4,4,4,4),
                  output2 = c(8,9,6,4,2))
```

Code:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  if(i ==1) {out <- df1}
  out <- left_join(out, df2 %>%
              select(str_subset(names(df2),paste0(i,"$"))),
              by = str_subset(str_subset(names(out),paste0(i,"$")), names(df2)))
}

out <- out %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.),0,.)))
```

Output:

```
  value1 value2 output1 output2
1      1      2       4       8
2      2      5       4       0
3      3      8       4       6
4      4      4       0       4
5      5      6       4       0
```

You can change the indices in the `for` loop parameters to the number of value you want to merge the dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with ifelse.

```
dataframeA<- data.frame(Column1 = c("a", "b", "c", "f"),
                        Column2 = c("a", "a", "a", "f"))
dataframeB<- data.frame(Column1 = c("b", "b", "c", "e"),
                        Column2 = c("a", "b", "a", "e"),
                        Output = c("B", "B", "B", "B"),
                        Output2 = c("D", "D", "D", "D"))
dataframeA <- dataframeA %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = ifelse(Column1 %in% dataframeB$Column1, dataframeB$Output,
                               ifelse(Column2 %in% dataframeB$Column2,dataframeB$Output2, 0 )))
```

UPDATE

```
dataframeA<- data.frame(Column1 = c("a", "b", "c", "f", "g"),
                        Column2 = c("a", "a", "a", "f", "g"))
dataframeB<- data.frame(Column1 = c("b", "b", "c", "e", "g"),
                        Column2 = c("a", "b", "a", "e", "g"),
                        Output = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                        Output2 = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D"))

dataframeA <- dataframeA %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = ifelse(Column1 %in% dataframeB$Column1 & Column2 %in% dataframeB$Column2, dataframeB$Output,
                               ifelse(Column2 %in% dataframeB$Column2,dataframeB$Output2, 
                                      ifelse(Column1 %in% dataframeB$Column1, dataframeB$Output, NA))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest to what I was asking. However, it does not work, it seems that if there is matches for both column 1 and column 2 and it returns NA. I am gonna use your example in my question :)

Comment: Check the update. the fourth row has no match so NA, and the fifth has a match in both and is output1.